# C# задача. В чем ошибка?

Tags: c#

Билет на одну поездку в метро стоит 15 рублей, билет на 10 поездок стоит 125 рублей, билет на 60 поездок стоит 440 рублей. Пассажир планирует совершить n поездок. Определите, сколько билетов каждого вида он должен приобрести, чтобы суммарное количество оплаченных поездок было не меньше n, а общая стоимость приобретенных билетов – минимальна.
Формат ввода

Дано одно число n - количество поездок.
Формат вывода

Выведите три целых числа, равные необходимому количеству билетов на 1, на 10, на 60 поездок.
Пример 1

Ввод
1
Вывод

1 0 0

```
using System;

class MainClass 
{ // Metro
  
  public static void Main (string[] args) 
  {
    string s;

    s = Console.ReadLine(); // Возвращает переменную типа string

    int n = int.Parse(s);

    int sixty = n / 60;
    
    n = n - sixty*60;
    int ten = n / 10;
    n = n - 10*ten;

    Console.WriteLine(n.ToString() + " " + ten.ToString() + " " + sixty.ToString());


  }
}
```

В чем ошибка, подскажите, пожалуйста...

Comment: а в чем проблема? Вам вроде справедливо показывает, что для 1 билета надо купить 1 билет.

Comment: А Вы не пробовали поискать по сайту - вдруг кто-то уже задавал такой вопрос?

Comment: вот это `n = n - sixty*60;` заменяется на `n = n % 60;`

Comment: @tym32167 все равно не работает

Comment: Что не работает то? Вы проблему так и не рассказали.

Comment: Артем она задачу неверно роняла. Нужно купить билетов не меньше чем n за наименьшую сумму

Comment: Тут нужно считать мин мах. Задачу нужно решить в лоб потом округлив до десятков и округлив до 60 и выбрать наименьшую сумму

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не до конца поняли условие задачи.

Необходимо купить не менее n билетов за наименьшую сумму.

У вас варианты.

1. Если n = 1..8 покупаем n*15
2. Если n = 9..10 покупаем 10 за 125
3. Если n = 11..18 покупаем 1*125 + (n-10)*15

....

4. Если n = 31..34 покупаем 3*125 + (n-30)*15 тут максимум 375+60 = 435
5. Если n = 35...60 покупаем 60 за 440

....

Думаю дальше нужно вычитать из произвольного n кратные и смотреть на результат

Comment: Извините реализовывать не стал. С телефона набираю